# Unity - Everything freezes on " yield return new WaitForSeconds(); "?

Tags: unity-game-engine, freeze, coroutine

Ok! all of my code in this scene is in one script and one manager object.
all of it is about 700 lines. so I can't put it here. 
I tested different things:

- 1) switch platform from android to
  pc/mac
- 2) test on a previous version
  of unity( previous 2017, and current
  on is 2018.1 )

none of them solve the problem.
then I change some part of the code that I suspected to cause the problem. ( none of them solve the solution ). 
then I started to put Debug.Log()s everywhere. so I found where it freezes.

Here Is the code:

```
    IEnumerator ShowSigns(int Button1State, int EqualState, int Button2State)
    {

        Debug.Log("ShowSigns");
        if (Button1State == 1)
        {
            OperationOneCorrectSign.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1;
        }
        else if (Button1State == 2)
        {
            OperationOneIncorrectSign.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1;
        }
        if (EqualState == 1)
        {
            EqualCorrectSign.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1;
        }
        else if (EqualState == 2)
        {
            EqualIncorrectSign.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1;
        }
        if (Button2State == 1)
        {
            OperationTwoCorrectSign.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1;
        }
        else if (Button2State == 2)
        {
            OperationTwoIncorrectSign.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1;
        }

        Debug.Log("BeforeWaiting");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);

        Debug.Log("AfterWaiting");
        OperationOneCorrectSign.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 0;
        OperationOneIncorrectSign.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 0;
        EqualCorrectSign.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 0;
        EqualIncorrectSign.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 0;
        OperationTwoCorrectSign.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 0;
        OperationTwoIncorrectSign.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 0;
        state = GameState.CreateNewProblem;

        Debug.Log("EndSigns");
    }
```

I found that it freezes on this:

```
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
```

Very strange!!!

This is a picture of the game.

[image]
The game is a simple game that shows 2 math phrase and player should choose the bigger or equal.
The logic is this way:

- 1) make new phrases and change the game state to "ChooseAnswer"
- 2) player press one of 3 buttons and the answer checked and score and other things changes and the ShowSigns coroutine will start and ends after 0.3 seconds. and as you see at the end of the coroutine state changes to "CreateNewProblem".
- 3) in the Update when CreateNewProblem detects, the code call for the NewProblem() function to make new phrases and at the end of that game state changes to "ChooseAnswer".

this logic repeats over and over until time reaches zero.
a "step" variable increase and decrease by 1 by any correct and incorrect answer. and a variable level = steps/10 determines the difficulty of phrases.

the game works correctly on %98 click On buttons. but usually, it freezes somewhere after step 20. In 21, 23, 27, 34 ... very randomly. but always after 20 and some time no freeze until time ends. and always right before yield return. exactly at the same line.

I read many questions and answers but none of them was helpful. I have no while loop, no while(true), as long as I know and check my code no infinite loop, on StopAllCoroutines ... nothing. and I stuck for 2 days. 
thanks all of you for helping.

[OH,and Here Is the code file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x1XrlSduj2LKFg3QoKjqgU4FKfDQpsSI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the freezing is using `Random.Range` to control a `while` loop which is in the code [linked](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x1XrlSduj2LKFg3QoKjqgU4FKfDQpsSI) in your question. One way to get random number without using the `while` loop is to generate them into `List` then remove each one you use. This should prevent `Random.Range` from freezing Unity.